# Dataframe with localized datetime index: how to drop days not having a given time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe like the following:

```
                            A   B
2014-06-02 09:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 10:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 11:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 12:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-03 09:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-03 10:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-03 11:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 09:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 10:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 11:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 12:00:00-04:00   ... ...
```

I need to drop the days that doesn't have the hour 12:00:00-04:00: In my example it would be the 2014-06-03. So the final dataframe would looks like:

```
                            A   B
2014-06-02 09:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 10:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 11:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 12:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 09:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 10:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 11:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 12:00:00-04:00   ... ...
```

Please note that the index is localized (-04:00)

pandas             0.24.2

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` and `filter`

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).filter(lambda s: 12 in s.index.hour)
```

```
                            A   B
2014-06-02 09:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 10:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 11:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-02 12:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 09:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 10:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 11:00:00-04:00   ... ...
2014-06-04 12:00:00-04:00   ... ...
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: @Alfonso_MA you don't have datetime index?? So you have strings as indexes? .... Make it datetime first.. `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a Boolean mask checking for `any` 12:00:00 by date, then subset.

```
import pandas as pd
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)  # So DatetimeIndex

m = (pd.Series((df.index - df.index.normalize()) == '12H',
               index=df.index)
       .groupby(df.index.normalize())
       .transform('any'))

df.loc[m]
                             A    B
2014-06-02 09:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
2014-06-02 10:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
2014-06-02 11:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
2014-06-02 12:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
2014-06-04 09:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
2014-06-04 10:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
2014-06-04 11:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
2014-06-04 12:00:00-04:00  ...  ...
```